# get error with bind tag in ant file

Tags: ant

i got this error while build application jar with ant

Problem: failed to create task or type bind
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

and this a snippet is my build.xml file:

Comment: Ant error should also refer to the problematic line number.  But it is difficult to say something if you don't show your build.xml

Comment: E:\Code\DRC workspace\sms\build.xml:93: Problem: failed to create task or type bind. this line <bind verbose="true" load="true" binding="mdb-src/com/arj/sms/xmlHandler/mapping/binding.xml">

Comment: Could you paste error, and also the build file to be able to get help from others

Answer (score 0):

Your `<bind verbose="true" load="true" binding="mdb-src/com/arj/sms/xmlHandler/mapping/binding.xml">`

requires task definition of JiBX binding compiler. Just like any other custom Ant task. To make it more clear `bind` is not a "ant tag" like you call it and isn't "part" of ant syntax. You need to define it:

`<taskdef name="bind" ..` + classname/classpaths/filesets etc..

You have it?

If you have it, then make sure that task definition has proper path to the lib directory of your JiBX installation. Also note that some versions of Ant may not work properly if the JiBX installation path contains a space character.

Good luck.